# Como posso desenvolver esse layout?

Tags: html5, css3

Eu estou a fazer um site conforme ilustrado abaixo, só que estou com um problema em fazer a `div` central. Não sei como devo fazer aquela parte onde esta a `nav` e `section`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Código:

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#redes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  margin—left: 10%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="redes">
      <h1>Redes Sociais</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    <nav>
      <p>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </p>
    </nav>
    <section>asad</section>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>
      &copy; Copyright by 
    </p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo que não use position absolute pra ajustar layouts, isto é muito dificil. Já tentou bootstrap?

Comment: Não ainda nao tentei mas o objectivo do que eu tou a fazer não e para ajuste a dispositivos moveis so no computador

Comment: sim queria saber o que estou a fazer de mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nav nesse simples exemplo está no meio e acima, mas você pode editar o código e deixar da forma que você quiser!

Por exemplo, você pode fazer o `aside` abaixo virar o seu `nav` do lado esquerdo, apenas mudando  os seguintes atributos no css:

`float:right` para  `float:left`, e `section` `float:right`.

Faça essa mudança e confira o resultado, veja que apenas invertemos os lados através do CSS, e você deve fazer assim com os demais para experimentar.

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

body{

}

.conteiner{
  width:80%;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
  background-color: chocolate;
  height: 160px;
}

ul{
overflow:hidden;
list-style:none;
}

li{
float:left;
width: 20%;/*DISTANCIA ENTRE OS ICONES*/
margin: 0 auto;
}

a{
 color:#fff;/*cor dos icones e textos dos icones*/
 padding:0px 40px ;/*tamanho do quadro de cada item de  menu na barra lateral*/
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 font-size:30px;
 text-align: center;
}

a:hover{
 background:black;
}

nav{
  background-color:#bdaac1;
  width: 90%;
  margin:auto;
}


section{
  background-color: pink;
  float:left;
  width:70%;
  height: 400px;
}

article{
 background-color: red;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100px;
}

aside{
 background-color: #f65b5b;
 float:right;
 width:30%;
 height: 400px;
}


footer{
  background: blue;
  clear:both;
}
.cor1{
background: yellow;
}
.cor2{
background: #5e5d85;
}

.cor3{
background: red;
}

#aMaior{
  height: 200px;
}
a
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name = "view port"   content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="conteiner">
 <header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <nav>
     <ul>     
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>    
      <li><a href="#">Trabalhos</a></li>    
      <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

 </header>
 <section>
  <h1 id="titulo">Section</h1>
  <article class="cor1"><h1>Article</h1></article>
  <article class="cor2"><h1>Article</h1></article>
  <article class="cor3"><h1>Article</h1></article>
 </section>
 <aside><h1>Aside</h1>
  <article class="cor1" id="aMaior"><h1>Article</h1></article>
 </aside>
 <footer><h1>Footer</h1></footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Veja no **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juL7faok/)** se é isso que você quer.